# Cypress trying to recursively create a folder

Tags: cypress

I have a Cypress downloaded in zip file for Windows  and extracted locally and when I am trying to run any tests, seems like Cypress recurively trying to create an integration/cypress/integration.. folder and failing

```
 Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, stat
```

`'C:\Users\user\work\sources\services\automation\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress\integration\cypress`

Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried change the default integration folder path in your cypress.json file?

Something like

```
integrationFolder: Another Path
```

if that solves the issue problably the integration Folder location was misconfigured